# PHP filter_var() function allowing more than one minus in integer numbers

Tags: php, regex, filter-var

I am trying to filter integers using [filter_var()](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), but in this case:

```
echo filter_var('-3-6-5', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); // Output: -3-6-5
```

Instead of -3-6-5 i expect to get -365.

Someone know how to solve this or a regex that do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you expect that? A bit of context would help...

Comment: @elclanrs, I am trying to sanitize some vars and then validate them

Comment: @Marcio Simao: `-3-6-5` should fail validation. You should show a error message back to user, not try to guess what they meant

Comment: the function's working AS DEFINED: "removes all characters except digits, plus, and minus signs". e.g. filtering `-3-6+5a` will give you `-3-6+5` as well. It doesn't claim to give you a VALID number, just something that COULD be a valid number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('~^[^-\d]|(?<!^)\D~', '', '-3-6-5'); // -365
```

It will remove anything that is not a digit, keeping `-` sign in the beginning of the string